# What is the difference between normal stickers and foil stickers in CS GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I bought one normal sticker for pick-em challenge and it cost 0.99$. Now it shows that I can sell it at 0.78$ but in market there are few foil stickers which are more expensive (7$ to 12$) but the stickers are the same. In my case it's team envious sticker so I'm kinda confused as to what the difference between normal and foil stickers are when there are holo stickers, too.

I have searched on Google and Steam community and found that foil stickers are shiny, normal ones are blue and foil stickers show different color. But all this is just a guess and no one is sure so can some one help me to find the difference?

The links I already found about this, but are no use are these:

- [What's the difference between the normal, holo and foil stickers? (on Steam)](http://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/558750717397208911/)
- [What's the difference between Holo stickers and foil stickers? (on Steam)](https://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/558747287644362202/)

Comment: I cannot find a good source to write an answer from, but have you seen these 2 links? http://blog.counter-strike.net/workshop/stickers/ & http://imgur.com/a/rIzo0

Comment: @ColinD, yes i have seen first link(second is new for me) but not able to understand the code part and why foil are costly..just because one extra strip? or shiny color?

Comment: They are more expensive because they are rarer and lots of people think they are cool.

Comment: well thanx for the comment colin but this is not that thing which i am looking for..but still thanx a lot :)

Comment: The only differenz between foil and not foil is the colore and the rarity. This is something steam made for the stickers in CS:GO and for some other items in the steam market e.g the Cards for each game can be aquired in "normal" and "foil". The Value of stuff in the market is connected to the amount of times player have the item and how easy it is to get the item. The chance of getting a foiled cards / stickers is reeeeeaaly small thats why the price is much higher then the price of normal ones. But all that is fictive cause its only ingame Value.

Comment: @GEnGEr, Thanx for your comment and info.. i have already mention that point about difference but i thought there will be any more point but ok.. i will try to dig more..ty for info...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Counter Strike: Global Offensive there are three different types of stickers. **Normal**, **Holo** and **Foil**.

## Rarity

These three types are also the rarity of the sticker. The rarity levels are the same as on skins in which **Normal** stickers are *Blue* (High Grade), **Holo** stickers *Purple* (Remarkable) and **Foil** stickers *Pink* (Exotic).

This means that **Normal** stickers are more often dropped than **Foil** stickers. This makes it harder to get **Holo** or **Foil** sticker.

## Appearance

Of course these types have all different appearance to gain a better look on higher rarity.

### Normal

Normal stickers are flat stickers that are attached on a weapon. These stickers do not have special effects except a weak glossy paper effect.

[image: Normal]

### Holo

Holographic stickers are like normal stickers but they have a holographic warping effect.

[image: Holo]

### Foil

Foil stickers have an embossed effect. So they do not look flat like the other two types and have a kinda 3D shape. They also have a metallic surface and shine in the light.

[image: Foil]

Keep in mind that I have simplified the complexity behind the real sticker. You can read most about the advanced specification on the [official sticker guide](http://blog.counter-strike.net/workshop/stickers/) for designers.

## Price

To get the price of these stickers you have to combine the rarity and the appearance. **Foil** stickers are more worth because they are much harder to get and (for some people) look better than **normal** sticker. Keep in mind that the appearance of a sticker is fully subjectively and every person likes another style.

The main reason why **Foil** or **Holo** sticker are more worth than **Normal** ones is because of the rarity.

<sub>Information from [counterstike wikia](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Stickers). Information and pictures from [counterstrike blog](http://blog.counter-strike.net/workshop/stickers/).</sub>

Comment: Well these all content from the given link before but still good work mate..accepted as answer..:)

Comment: @Leothelion Oh dident saw that link. I just read your question. Yes I used the same site but I think I explained it very well without the code parts.

Answer (score 2):

When you put the sticker on a gun, the normal sticker will look normal. While the foil looks shiny (Changing color when the lightning change).

Comment: well thanx for the answer but i have already added that line and even in comments too..still thanx

Comment: Other than that, price and rarity. There is no other changes.

Comment: well i already added 2 points and link with differences but i don't think because of that they are costly so i asked..

Comment: Well, that's only the difference.